# What is queueName?

Tags: jquery, deque

In this code:

```
$('.slide').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
```

Is this how to use dequeue() function? Cause it says dequeue( [ queueName ] ) in jQuery website. Because I want to dequeue the fadeOut(); Is fadeOut the queueName?

It this the way to use dequeue() function?

```
$('.slide').dequeue('fadeOut');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. There is a default queue to which all effect methods are added which is called `fx`. See the [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) documentation:

> Every element can have one to many queues of functions attached to it by jQuery. In most applications, only one queue (called `fx`) is used. Queues allow a sequence of actions to be called on an element asynchronously, without halting program execution.

You can create other queues with other names.

The argument you pass to `dequeue` is the name of the queue, not of a function. So you probably want `$('.slide').dequeue('fx');`, which is the same as `$('.slide').dequeue();`.